# why data frame length greater than 16383 byte in http 2.0

Tags: http

when I read 《Hign Performance Browser Networking》, at end of chapter 12, it say: in http 2.0, data frame could not greater than 16383 bytes.If the length exceeds this threshold, it will be sent in frames

I'm confuse about this. Can anyone answer this question.  If the length exceeds this threshold(16383 bytes), it will be sent in frames

Comment: Can you try to elaborate what confuses you? Do you know what data frames are in HTTP 2? Do you just want to know why it's 16383 and not something else?

Comment: Data frames contains application data.In binary framing header defination, lenth contains 16 Bit,so Its maximum value is 65535 bytes. I'm confuse about what limit the data frame length(16373 bytes) and why greater than it should  split frame.